# In html how to pass div class content (text) to another class or id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, i have `<div id="titlebar"></div>` inside html, and also i have `<div class="name">Content-text</div>` inside same html. Now i want pass Content-text of div class name (`<div class="name">Content-text</div>`) to another my id `<div id="titlebar"></div>` through `css` or `js`. i tried several ways, but no effect

And when i scroll up the html the id `titlebar` will show the text of class `name`

My html:

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="titlebar"></div>
      <div class="name">Content-text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
 #titlebar{
 text-align:center;
 width: 101%;
 position: fixed;
 top:0px;
 margin-left:-10px;
 padding-right:1px;
 font-family: Times New Roman;
 font-size: 16pt;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: white;
 display:none;
 border: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
 window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

 function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {

    document.getElementById("titlebar").style.display = "block";
} else {

    document.getElementById("titlebar").style.display = "none";
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Sample, jsFiddle**
Please find it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5bp7wt0o/).

```
<style>
#titlebar{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.name{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<div>
   <div id="titlebar"></div>
   <br/>
  <div class="name">Content-text</div>
  <button id='btn'>
    Click to cpoy and put text inside titlebar
  </button>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

// Find your required code hre 


let textInsideDivelementWithclass = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText,
    titlebarEle = document.getElementById('titlebar');
  titlebarEle.innerText =  textInsideDivelementWithclass;


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var Content_text = $(".name").text();
    $("#titlebar").text(Content_text);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Copy</button>

<div class="name">Content-text</div>
<div id="titlebar">copy here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you get the text of your .name element:

```
let nameElement = document.querySelector(".name").textContent;
```

then you get the target element and assign the .name text to it :

```
document.querySelector("#titlebar").textContent = nameElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should determin an id for your div like this:

`<div id="name">Content-text</div>`

then use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var DivName = document.getElementById('name');
   var DivTitlebar = document.getElementById('titlebar');
   DivTitlebar.innerHTML = DivName.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

You have to get the content from the `div1` and `div2` to two seperate variables `div1Data` and `div2Data`

Then from the **[HTML DOM innerHTML Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)** you can assign the content to your preferred `div`

```js
function copyContent() {
  var div1Data= document.getElementById('div1');
  var div2Data= document.getElementById('div2');
  div2Data.innerHTML = div1Data.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  Content in div 1
</div>

<div id="div2">
</div>

<button onClick="copyContent()">Click to copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var Content_text = $(".name").text();
  //alert(Content_text);
  $(function() {

$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, scroll) {

 if (scroll > 0) $('#titlebar').text('Content_text');
 else $('#titlebar').text('Copy here');

 return false;
});
});
    //$("#titlebar").text(Content_text);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="name" style="margin-top:50px;">Content-text</div>
<div id="titlebar" style="margin-top:50px;">Copy here</div>

</body>
</html>
```